# CSV File import in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a histogram from a CSV file using Python with pandas and matplotlib in **Google Collab**.

The link to the CSV I used: https://code.datasciencedojo.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/tree/f79a29c33657fb7ac39c2d609d56205c2e5cb0a4/Online%20News%20Popularity

Here's my code:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

!gdown 1Ma0yJKy9Zs18g8sN5IJZmwABT4WaFz1G
os.listdir()[1]

data = pd.read_csv('OnlineNewsPopularity.csv')
data.head()

plt.hist(data['num_hrefs'], bins=30)
plt.xlabel('Website')
plt.ylabel('Number of Clicks')
plt.title('Website Popularity Statitcs')
plt.show()
```

---

### keyerror: num_hrefs

The dataset is properly being loaded into the Google Collab file, and the data.head() is showing it properly. I have already checked that the 'num_hrefs' column exists in my CSV file. Could anyone please help me identify the issue and suggest a solution?

I have made sure that num_hrefs is correctly spelled and capitalized. I thought maybe the underscore was creating errors so I used a column called 'shares' with the same code, but it didn't work either. I assume it's not properly reading my code for some reason, however, it shows the correct dataset when printing data.head()

Comment: Truly strange behaviour. I've been investigating... In your case `data.iloc[:, 7]` works, but `print('num_hrefs' in [col.strip() for col in data.columns])` indeed prints True with that csv, can't see why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is because your CSV columns are separated by `,`  instead of just `,`.

`data.columns` gives:

```
Index(['url', ' timedelta', ' n_tokens_title', ' n_tokens_content',
       ' n_unique_tokens', ' n_non_stop_words', ' n_non_stop_unique_tokens',
       ' num_hrefs', ' num_self_hrefs', ' num_imgs', ' num_videos',
...
```

You can see that whitespaces are included. It could work if you access by `data[' num_hrefs']`.

But what you really want is to use the `skipinitialspace=True` option when reading the file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(..., skipinitialspace=True)
```